# Distinguish between const and non-const method with same name in boost::bind

Tags: c++, boost, boost-bind

When I use `boost::bind` with a method name which is declared both const and non-const I am getting in ambiguous error, for example

```
boost::bind( &boost::optional<T>::get, _1 )
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem together with workarounds is descibed in FAQ part of [Boost.Bind](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/bind/bind.html#err_overloaded) reference.

You could also make use of utility functions like the following:

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/optional.hpp>

template <class Ret, class Obj>
Ret (Obj::* const_getter(Ret (Obj::*p) () const)) () const
{
    return p;
}

template <class Ret, class Obj>
Ret (Obj::* nonconst_getter(Ret (Obj::*p)())) ()
{
    return p;
}

int main()
{
    boost::bind( const_getter(&boost::optional<int>::get), _1 );
    boost::bind( nonconst_getter(&boost::optional<int>::get), _1 );
}
```

Comment: Thank your for both suggestions. I prefer the cast workaround in the Boost.Bind FAQ and used this now in my source code.

Comment: For the record, the cast workaround is this: given you want to bind a function `int Foo::get() const`, instead of binding `&Foo::get`, bind `static_cast<int(Foo::*)() const>(&Foo::get)`